# RunTime Error in Unity when I'm using a function from a C++ Dll

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dll

I'm using a Dll created from a C++ file. When I either put the .dll and .lib files in my Unity-project folder or when I use the function that I need, Unity crashes and I can't open the project untile I remove the .dll or delete the function from the c# script.

This function works well on C++, both in Visual Studio and in Dev-C++
PS: Assets/alzBraccioCorretto.json is the file that I need to read

I've tried the same procedure for more simple dlls and it worked fine, so I don't know what I'm missing with this one.

In the Unity script I wrote

```
[DllImport("QuartaLibreria.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]

static extern int LeggiFile(string nomeFile);
Text testo;
unsafe void Start()
{
    testo = GetComponent<Text>();
    int temp = 0;
    temp = LeggiFile("Assets/alzBraccioCorretto.json");
    testo.text = temp.ToString();
}
```

In the header of the library I have

```
#define QUARTALIBRERIA_API __declspec(dllexport)

//all the other headers and #include

int converti_int(string frame);//returns reads a line and returns an int

int leggiFile(string nomeFile);

extern "C" {
QUARTALIBRERIA_API int LeggiFile(wstring nomeFile);
}
```

In the cpp of the library I have

```
int leggiFile(string nomeFile) {

ifstream _stream(nomeFile.c_str());
int temp;
_stream >> temp >> temp >> temp >> temp >> temp;
return temp;
}


QUARTALIBRERIA_API int LeggiFile(wstring nomeFile){
std::string str = std::string(nomeFile.begin(), nomeFile.end());
int daRit = leggiFile(str);
return daRit;
}
```

Comment: You may want to check this inconsistency:  `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` and then `char * FileName` -- A `char *` does not represent (at least not on the surface) a Unicode string.  Also an aside -- your `LockOn` function allocates memory, but who is responsible for deallocating that memory?  Unless you have some sort of strategy to do this, your implementation will leak memory.

Comment: I'll try immediatly the deallocation. I have it in the C++ script but I forgot to do it here.
For the "char thing", do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What is `lockPerson`?  What is the type it is expecting as the first parameter?  Simply put, a Unicode (wide string) is not a narrow string (char array).  [Unicode character sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), and possibly your messing up things by providing the wrong / mismatch string types.

Comment: I thing the error might be in the string/char mistakes I made. Because all the other used variables  are created inside the function, so they should be automatically deleted when it ends.
I try to explain lockPerson in the edited question

Comment: If you post the signature of the `lockPerson` function, then an answer can be crafted and placed here.  It doesn't matter what it does, we need to see the signature of the function, i.e. the parameter list and the types.

Comment: You mean the script?
I'm sorry for inexperience, I'm new to programming :D

Comment: What is the declaration of this function?  What are the parameter types?  You need to know basic C++ nomenclature.  Every function in C++ must either be declared or implemented in full before anyone can call the function.  Somewhere that `lockPerson` function is declared and/or implemented.

Comment: int lockPerson(char* filename, double lsxx, double lsxy, double udxx, double udxy, double timer)

I kept the declaration of the two functions pretty much the same

Comment: Thank you.  If this lockPerson function then goes on and calls other functions that expect a Unicode string, but instead getting an "ASCII" string as you're doing, then things get out of hand.  Get the string handling consistent -- either everything is Unicode, or everything is non-Unicode, or you know darn well how to go back and forth between the two character set types.  Not an answer, but something you need to clean up first.

Comment: Also, a `wchar_t` instead of `char` is the character type to use for Unicode.

Comment: Thank you anyway for taking the time to respond me! <3 I'll let you know if this works!
Ok! Now I'll try this

Comment: Hi @PaulMcKenzie, I changed a few things in the code but it still doesn't work! Do you have any idea why :( By the way, I found some code that you posted on CodeGuru in 2002!